# jQuery passing multiple parmeters to a custom selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters to a custom jQuery selector. But if I pass them like

`$("div:myselector('param1','param2')")` I get param1','param2 .

Passing them with a space at the beginning `$("div:myselector( 'param1','param2')")` seems to work (I'm recieving 'param1','param2' with it) but there should be a proper solution. Does anybody know how to handle that the right way or did I understand something basically wrong ?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple ! why not using object ?
you can pass one by one and add to javascript object

```
     var x=new Object();
     x.y=$('#param1').val();
     x.z=$('#param1').val();
```